# Change default date on date_parser of Pandas on Python

Tags: python, date, pandas, time

I have a dataset that look like this:

```
refrigerator.csv
08/02/2012 00:00:02;136;134
08/02/2012 00:00:03;134;134
08/02/2012 00:00:05;136;134
08/02/2012 00:00:06;136;134
08/02/2012 00:00:08;134;134
08/02/2012 00:00:09;134;134
...
```

I would like to change the date that is always 08/02/2012 to 01/01/2010. I tried to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
refr=pd.read_csv('C:/refrigerator.csv', names=['ts', 'P1', 'P2'], 
                  sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, 
                  date_parser=lambda x: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01 %s' %x))
```

But I get a ValueError. In short I would like to keep the time as it is, and change the date. The reason is because I have multiple datasets and each one represents a daily power profile of an appliance. I don't care about the date, only the time. I would like to read all of them with the same date in order to sync them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try first convert to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then `replace` in `date_parser`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
08/02/2012 00:00:02;136;134
08/02/2012 00:00:03;134;134
08/02/2012 00:00:05;136;134
08/02/2012 00:00:06;136;134
08/02/2012 00:00:08;134;134
08/02/2012 00:00:09;134;134"""


#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df =pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=['ts', 'P1', 'P2'], 
                  sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, 
                  date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).replace(year=2010, month=1,day=1))

print df
                      P1   P2
ts                           
2010-01-01 00:00:02  136  134
2010-01-01 00:00:03  134  134
2010-01-01 00:00:05  136  134
2010-01-01 00:00:06  136  134
2010-01-01 00:00:08  134  134
2010-01-01 00:00:09  134  134
```